# Gather employee information scattered in two tables

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem with [Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RYP9PL8TNneie8uvlKRUCrS5gAiFrnIh0VbIBdGCQsk/edit?usp=sharing). In one of my sheets, I have two tables. The first contains the employee ID and the total hours; and the second has for each employee, his/her name and ID. Example:

[image: Sample spreadsheet]!

I am trying to figure out a formula to look through the second table and if it sees a certain employee ID then it will assign that employee ID with the person's name. I would like to keep the column that lists the employee ID but to have a formula that places the person’s name near to his/her ID. The problem is that I do not know how to stick such information. For instance, in D4 should appear "Ben Hale" because the employee ID of E4 matches with the ID that appears in E25.

The expected output is in red (except the value of E18). I want to obtain such output using formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=index(F$22:F$37,match(E3,$E$22:$E$37,0))
```

copied down to suit.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the valuable contribution of pnuts, you could also use enter the following in D4:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(E3:E17, E22:F37, 2,0))
```